# Android paging library with sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, paging, android-room, android-livedata

Can I use android paging library using sqlite database directly with pojo instead of using Room but by using LiveData. I don't want to use Room for that. 
Purpose is to solve the lag between data loading event after using simple pagination technique while fetching the large amount of data.

I am referring to the doc:

- https://proandroiddev.com/8-steps-to-implement-paging-library-in-android-d02500f7fffe
- https://medium.com/mindorks/pagination-using-paging-library-with-rxjava-and-dagger-d9d05dbd8eac

and I want to fetch data from sqlite in place of retrofit data loading in above method. Is it ok ?

Comment: do you get any solution for pagination?